# Equivariant resolution of singularities with equivariant centres

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, cv.complex-variables, complex-geometry

From what I understand, given a complex projective variety X inside a compact complex manifold Y, according to Hironaka, there is a sequence of $r$ blowups $Y_i$ of Y along complex submanifolds (centres) $C_i$ such that the proper transform $\tilde{X}$ of $X$ in $Y_r$ is smooth. By functoriality, if $G$ is say, a compact connect Lie group, acting on $Y$ such that $X$ is invariant, then there is a lift of this action to $Y_r$ such that $\tilde{X}$ is also invariant.

My questions are as follows :
 1. Does the above work even if $X$ is reducible ?
 2. Can the centres $C_i$ be chosen to be invariant under $G$ ?

Comment: I do not believe the original proof was stated as functorial in the way that you write.  However, it is now known that there is a resolution algorithm that is "functorial" for smooth morphisms, e.g., for actions of a (necessarily smooth) complex Lie group.  This should be in the book by Koll\'ar on resolution of singularities.  Cheers Vamsi -- I hope that this helps!